# Add a padding to the container with Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Using Twitter Bootstrap, I'm looking for a way to **add padding left, or margin left, to the container of the page**. (expressed in units of percentage of the page)

In fact, if I don't include bootstrap-responsive.css, the padding is quite good for me. But I would like that my website works fine on mobiles. So it is necessary to include this file, and a direct effect (why ?) is that the padding-left (or margin-left, I don't know) is less important.

I've tried to add manually padding-left or margin-left to the container class in my own CSS, but it enlarges the width of the page and creates an horizontal scroll-bar.

Do you know a safe way to do it, maybe using tools provided by Bootstrap ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There maybe other ways but try sth. like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span2"></div>
        <div class="span8">
            Content
        </div>
        <div class="span2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This makes your page responsive and narrower at same time. About [bootstrap fluidgridsystem](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#fluidGridSystem).

Comment: It's almost perfect. The only problem is that when I reduce the page, the empty span2 goes over span8 and creates a visible space. Is there a solution ?

Comment: Little hacky but `<div class="span2" style="line-height:0px;"/>` is going to work.

Comment: `style="min-height:1px;"` even more hacky :)

Comment: First time logging onto Stack, but I found the above way, even with "span1" on either side of "span10" was too much padding. I instead, created a new css of specifics for my site and added a class after the "row-fluid" called "padding2" and gave it "padding: 2%". Any reason this is a bad idea? I'm new to bootstrap. Thanks!

Comment: @brendaard Bootstrap style handling is quite different, when you start to define your own css classes and mix them via bootstrap ones, it is going to be complicated to use or decide to proper class for other components. Therefore, before start to customize bootstrap css you should have a look into [here](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/customize.html) and decide proper values for your project then download and use your customized files.

Comment: But surely, deciding proper values without writing your own classes for a few development cycles; is impossible. But when you are ready to go with certain values go and customize files directly from bootstrap page. This is not a must, but it is going to be best practice.

Answer (score 5):

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8">
      Content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```